# Bash Script SQLITE - Too Many Options

Tags: bash, sqlite

Can't figure this one out, if I execute the command directly in the shell, then it executes successfully, but running from a script file I get the following error:

sqlite3: Error: too many options: "INTO"

```
#!/bin/bash
sql="\"INSERT INTO keys ('date','chan','key','name','desc','ser','ep','cat') VALUES('xxx','xxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxxx.','xxx','xxx','xxxx');\""      
echo $sql
sqlite3 mydb.db $sql
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be ?

Comment: Double quote the `$sql` variable in the script: `sqlite3 mydb.db "$sql"`

Comment: @h3nr1x Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quote the `$sql` variable in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sql="\"INSERT INTO keys ('date','chan','key','name','desc','ser','ep','cat') VALUES('xxx','xxx','xxxx','xxxx','xxxxx.','xxx','xxx','xxxx');\""      
echo $sql
sqlite3 mydb.db "$sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the binary I execute:

```
cat  /opt/sbin/sqlite3:
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
/opt/sbin/sqlite3.real $@
```

So if I execute /opt/sbin/sqlite3.real I have no problems.